# Is it possible to convert boolean operations to addition/multiplication modulo $2$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I mean, is it possible to convert `AND` `OR` `NOT` to simple algebraic expressions?

If it's not possible, how do you prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: My thought on this is that it may be impossible, but I don't have a proof yet. It's like how to prove there's no formula to quintic equations, not that easy IMO.

Comment: If you allow subtraction or the constant $-1$, this is possible even without needing to work mod 2.

Comment: @Magma can you post your answer? Basically, how to do `AND` `OR` `NOT` in purely algebraic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the "boolean operations" you mentioned are "boolean functions", i.e. functions of the form $f:\{0, 1\}^{k} \to \{0, 1\}$. Any boolean function can be expressed as a combination of [NAND gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) (which is called functional completeness of NAND gate), and we have $\mathrm{NAND}(x, y) = 1 - xy$, so it is possible.

Comment: Can you show how to express `OR`, `AND` ,`NOT` with NAND only?

Comment: First, $\mathrm{NOT}(x) = \mathrm{NAND}(x, x)$. Then $\mathrm{AND}(x, y) = \mathrm{NOT}(\mathrm{NAND}(x, y))$ and $\mathrm{OR}(x,y)=\mathrm{NOT}(\mathrm{AND}(\mathrm{NOT}(x), \mathrm{NOT}(y)))$ also can be expressed only with $\mathrm{NAND}$.

Comment: Cool! Do you also know how many different **basis** of boolean operations are there for `OR, AND ,NOT` ?

Comment: If you mean **basis** as a **functionally complete set**, then $\{\mathrm{NOR}\}$ or $\{\mathrm{NOT}, \mathrm{AND}\}$ are also the examples. See Wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate

Comment: Do you know the general method to find all **functionally complete set** for boolean algebra?

Comment: @user3698446 Maybe the most naive way is to add functions until the set can express $\mathrm{NAND}$. I don't know any efficient methods for it. Maybe someone would answer instead of me.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, classic Boolean logic is equivalent to operations on $\mathbb Z_2$. You might be aware that $\land,\mathrm{xor}$ similar to $\cup,\triangle$ on sets create the structure of a ring.

But there is up to isomorphy only one ring with to elements, which is $\mathbb Z_2$. In fact we can easily see $\land\sim +$ and $\mathrm{xor} \sim \cdot$: $a+b = 1$ exactly if either $a=1$ or $b=1$ but not both. $a\cdot b = 1$ exactly if $a=1$ and $b=1$.

Furthermore we can also easily see that $\lnot$ corresponds to $+1$.

This suffices to express any other possible logical operation:

$a\lor b = \lnot(\lnot a \land \lnot b) \sim 1 + ((1+a)(1+b)) = ab + a + b \sim (a\land b) \,\mathrm{xor}\, a \,\mathrm{xor}\, b $

$a\rightarrow b = \lnot a \lor b \sim (1+a)b + (1+a) + b = ab + a + 1$

and so on.

Comment: Also a great answer!